# Lambda task timeout but no application log

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a python lambda that triggers by S3 uploads to a specific folder. The lambda function is to process the uploaded file and outputs it to another folder on the same S3 bucket.

The issue is that when I do a bulk upload using AWS console, some files do not get processed. I ended up setting a dead letter queue to catch these invocations. While inspecting the message in the queue, there is a request ID which I tried to find it in the lambda logs.

[image]

These are the logs for the request ID:

[image]

Now the odd part is that in the python code, the first line after the imports is `print('Loading function')` which does not show up in the lambda log?

Added the python code here. It should still print the `Processing file name: " + key` which is inside the handler ya?

```
import urllib.parse
from datetime import datetime

import boto3

from constants import CONTENT_TYPE, XML_EXTENSION, VALIDATING
from xml_process import *
from s3Integration import download_file

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    print("Processing file name: " + key)
    try:
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        xml_content = response["Body"].read()
        content_type = response["ContentType"]

        tree = ET.fromstring(xml_content)
        key_file_name = key.split("/")[1]

        # Creating a temporary copy by downloading file to get the namespaces
        temp_file_name = "/tmp/" + key_file_name
        download_file(key, temp_file_name)
        namespaces = {node[0]: node[1] for _, node in ET.iterparse(temp_file_name, events=['start-ns'])}

        for name, value in namespaces.items():
            ET.register_namespace(name, value)

        # Preparing path for file processing
        processed_file = key_file_name.split(".")[0] + "_processed." + key_file_name.split(".")[1]
        print(processed_file, "processed")

        db_record = XMLMapping(file_path=key,
                               processed_file_path=processed_file,
                               uploaded_by="lambda",
                               status=VALIDATING, uploaded_date=datetime.now(), is_active=True)
        session.add(db_record)
        session.commit()

        if key_file_name.split(".")[1] == XML_EXTENSION:
            if content_type in CONTENT_TYPE:
                xml_parse(tree, db_record, processed_file, True)
            else:
                print("Content Type is not valid. Provided value: ", content_type)
                
        else:
            print("File extension is not valid. Provided extension: ", key_file_name.split(".")[1])
            
        return "success"
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
       
        raise e
```

I don't think its a permission issue as other files uploaded in the same batch were processed successfully.

Comment: What is your code and lambda permissions?

Comment: printing information outside of the handler will only be logged once: at the first invocation. The subsequent invocation will just invoke the handler code until the lambda execution environment is shut down by lambda. So, you should see a loading function somewhere earlier in your log. Please also share the lambda code and permissions. Without those there not much information we can provide.

Comment: also, I'd suggest to send notification to SQS since you have bulked uploads. That would avoid invoking lambda in parallel as well and avoiding cold start as much as possible. Processing events in batch is a good practice.